# Firebase observe by value fetches old value from cached data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have been facing some issues with firebase persistence once enabled, I had a chance to read through the rest of posted questions and reviewed there answers but still haven't got things to work as expected.

I have enabled firebase persistence and using observe by value to fetch recent update of particular node. Not only it keeps fetching old values but also once I leave a particular view controller and go back to that view controller the value changes to recent one.

Is there a proper way to request for recent value at first call?

**Code I have tried:**

```
 // MARK: Bill authenticate function

func authenticateBill(completion: @escaping (_ bill: Double?, _ billStatus: BillError?) -> Void) {

    // Observe incase bill details exist for current case
    let billRef = self.ref.child("bills").child((caseRef?.getCaseId())!)

    billRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (billSnapshot) in

        if !billSnapshot.exists() {
            completion(nil, BillError.unavailable)
            return
        }

        if let billDictionary = billSnapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let cost =  billDictionary["cost"] as! Double

            print("Cost: ", cost)

            completion(cost, nil)
        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, with persistence enabled, your first callback will contain the immediately-available value from the cache (if any), followed by updates from the server (if any).  You can't indicate to the SDK that you want either cached or fresh data.

If you want to keep a particular location up to date all the time while persistence is enabled, you can use keepSynced to indicate to the SDK it should always be listening and caching the data at that location.  That comes at an indeterminate cost in bandwidth, depending on how frequently the data changes.

You can use the REST API to request fresh data without going through any caching mechanisms.

Comment: I did try adding *keepSync* with true value but still experiencing the same issue, at first loads old value and later loads new value @DougStevenson